# Modelling Many Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I should model my database for a parent model with many has_one associations (20+). I have one model called House which is the parent model of all the other models:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :kitchen
  has_one :basement
  has_one :garage
  has_one :common_room
  #... Many other child models
end
```

All the child models contain unique properties specific to their own class. I've thought about STI, but there isn't really any shared functionality or inputs that I can use across models. I've also thought of making one 'super model', but that doesn't really follow Rails best practices, plus it would contain over 200 columns. Is there another design pattern or structure that I can use to model this efficiently so that I can reduce database calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class House
  has_many :rooms
  Room::TYPES.each do |room_type|
    has_one room_type, -> { where(room_type: room_type) }, class_name: "Room"
  end

class Room
  belongs_to :house
  TYPES = %i/kitchen basement garage common_room etc/.freeze
end
```

In your migration make sure to `add_index :rooms, [:type, :house_id], unique: true`. Unless a house can have more than 1 type of room.  If that is the case, I think a different approach is needed.

To your second question, it depends really, what type of database are you using? If its PostgreSQL you could use hstore and store those as a properties hash. Or you could serialize you db to take that as a hash. Or you could have another model that room has many of. For instance has_many :properties and make a property model that would store that information. Really depends on what else you want to do with the information

Comment: How would I then store unique properties for each model? I.e. Kitchen has booleans 'pantry', 'island' etc, Basement has properties 'finished', 'walk_out'? (Edited my original post for this new info)

Comment: depends really, what type of database are you using? If its PostgreSQL you could use hstore and store those as a properties hash.  Or you could serialize you db to take that as a hash.  Or you could have another model that room has many of.  For instance `has_many :properties` and make a property model that would store that information.  Really depends on what else you want to do with the information.

Comment: Yep I'm using PostgreSQL. Hstore is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Cheers Mate!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Polymorphism in Rails? It would be much simpler

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :properties, as: :property_house
end

class Kitchen < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property_house, polymorphic: true
end

class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property_house, polymorphic: true
end
```

For more information, go here: http://terenceponce.com/blog/2012/03/02/polymorphic-associations-in-rails-32/

Comment: The reason I chose not to do this is because each child model (Kitchen, Garage, etc.) all have different attributes that need to be persisted to the db. So I would end up with a table with over 200 boolean fields, which is not something I want to deal with.

Comment: @Mike I don't quite understand your point. Polymorphic means you will need separate table for each child model. Ex: kitchens for Kitchen model, garages for Garage model, etc... You will not have a single table for all child models

Comment: @Mike Or you mean that you want to have 1 single table to store all child model?