# How to structure these models associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am basically trying to create an app which allows a user to track what they are working on. So each user will have many projects.

Now each project can have a certain number of types e.g. videos, websites, articles, books etc. with each of these types of projects having many objects (i.e. a videos project would list all the videos they were working on, books project may have a list of books they read).

Each of these objects would have different variables (books might have author and length and websites may have URL, rank etc.)

How would I set up these models in rails?

So basically would I separate my project model from my type model (so project has_one type and type belongs_to project) and then have 4 separate object models (i.e. objectsite) for each of the different types?

Or is there a better way to design this.

[Modelling Many Rails Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986640/modelling-many-rails-associations)

I read this question and I think this may be similar to what I want to do but am not entirely sure as I don't full understand it.

UPDATE**
So far I have:

```
Projects 
has_one type

Type
belongs_to projects
has_many objects

object
belongs_to type
```

But I am not to sure if this is the best way to go about it because like I said each object for each type will be different

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and comunity may help you to fix problems you have. But nobody really like to do it without your efforts.

Comment: The best responses on SO come from specific questions - so you're going to get downvoted by the hardliners (just a warning) :)

Comment: I just updated the question to include what I have, is this better?

Comment: You can just have two models,**`User`** and **`Project`**.For different projects you can have a **`project_type`** attribute in the Project model to handle that.OR you have to take a look at **`STI`**.

Comment: Yep - I was writing an answer anyway, but if you're wondering why you're getting downvoted, the reason will be SO is like a science class - you need to be as specific as possible

Comment: ah ok cheers for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could bring myself to read, I'd recommend this:

**Models**

> So each user will have many projects.

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
end
```

---

**Vars**

> Each of these objects would have different variables (books might have
>   author and length and websites may have URL, rank etc.)

There are two ways to interpret this

The first is if you *know* what details your different objects will require, you could include them as attributes in their respective datatables. If you don't know, you'll have to use another table to populate them.

I'll detail both approaches for you:

--

**Known Attributes**

As `Pavan` mentioned in the comments, you'll likely benefit from an [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) for this:

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :books, class_name: "Project::Books"
   has_many :folders, class_name: "Project::Folders"
end

#app/models/object.rb
Class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | type | project_id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :project
end

#app/models/project/book.rb
Class Book < Object
   ... stuff in here
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
project = Project.find(params[:id])
project.books.each do |book|
   book.field1
end
```

--

**Unknown Attributes**

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :objects
end

#app/models/object.rb
Class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project
   has_many   :options
end

#app/models/option.rb
Class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | object_id | name | value | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :object
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
project = Project.find(params[:id])
project.objects.first.options.each do |option|
   option.name  #-> outputs "name" of attribute (EG "length")
   option.value #-> outputs "value" of attribute (EG "144")
end
```

This means you can use `option` to populate the various attributes your `objects` may require.

Comment: Thanks all this, this definitely made it a lot clearer for me. I think  I will go with a known attributes. Just to clarify, this means that each type of project would have its own model (inside a folder model/project)? Then I add all the attributes to the object class and only call the ones that are approriate for that specific object?

Thanks again for taking the time to go through and make this extremely clear for me!

Comment: No problem sir! The recommendation I gave was for [Single Table Inheritance](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance). You should look at [this site](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) to give you an idea on how it works

Comment: Ok thanks. Just had a look there - because you have put "Project::books" in the project model does that mean I don't need to include this route as that page suggests? `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]`

Comment: I think you'll need to include that, yes (sorry I forgot that). Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks i added that in. I got it all to work but had to change `has_many :books, class_name: "Project::Books"` to `has_many :books, class_name: "Book"` to get it to work otherwise I kept getting an uninitialized constant error

Comment: Yeah it works well I think (I tried to test it all out in the console and it seemed to). Thanks again

Comment: No problem! I am really proud of the answer :D